# TR-31 Key Exchange Mode of Use

Tags: key-exchange

Using TR-31 key exchange, how is it possible to use restrictive modes of use, such as V (Verify only)? If Alice were to generate such a key, and send it to Bob, Bob would not be able to generate a MAC for Alice to verify. Can this be solved without leaving the safe bounds of Key Blocks?
To be specific, I am referring to ASC X9 TR 31-2018, Interoperable Secure Key Exchange Key Block Specification.

Comment: Not quite clear on your question, are you asking what is the purpose of modes such as verify only?

Comment: @satur9nine If the key is defined as verify only and the header cannot be changed how will the MAC be generated?

Answer (score 1):

The mode of use rules prescribed in the header are rules that apply to wrapped key contained within the confidential data section of the key block. The mode of use rules are not applicable to the key block protection key (KBPK). The MAC section of the TR-31 key block itself is generated by the KBPK and thus the mode of rules do not apply to that particular MAC.

Regarding general cryptography, generating and verifying a MAC involve performing identical cryptographic operations, the only difference being at the end of verifying you compare the locally computed MAC with the MAC received to determine authenticity.

Thus I would presume that "verify only" mode of use rule means the key being delivered within the TR-31 key block should be used to compute and check the MAC on received messages but should not be used to create MACs on new messages.